# Spring batch jdbctemplate fetching wrong data

Tags: java, spring, join, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

We have spring batch implementation for data fetch and write to a file. We are using Oracle 11G along with spring jdbctemplate to fetch data. We have RowMapper implementation to fetch and populate bean. For normal run it is working fine, but in case of 100K of rows for few rows columns are inconsistent. e.g. we have 3 columns C1, C2 and C3. C2 column is repeating for different rows. It not properly fetch and update the column.

Please help to resolve the issue.

The issue was not at java level. At DB itself procedure was inserting inconsistent data due to Oracle issue with explicit join. In case of using explicit join for query and inserting huge number of rows there was issue. We are still analysing root cause at Oracle level but not able to identify.

Comment: I doubt it is the `JdbcTemplate` but your query not returning the results you expected.

Comment: Query is simple and straight to fetch columns from one table. I also suspecting issues with jdbctemplate or cache of OJDBC. Do you ever faced issue somthing like that.

Comment: No I haven't hence I doubt the fact that it is the `JdbcTemplate` as it is nothing more then a convenience wrapper making it easier to work with the JDBC API.

Comment: Post your code, then we can help you more.

Comment: @RahulDey Could you add more detail or examples of your problem?.. The question is not clear enough.

Comment: @Xstian It is spring batch for extracting data to a file. At the very first step we are populating single table quering different tables. After populating that table, we are extracting the same to file. We are using Reader-Writer process for the same. In reader we have Extension of RowMapper to fetch from resultset and set the value of bean params. By using FlatFileItemWriter we are converting the bean to flatfile. The fetching query for reader-RowMapper is straight selection of different fields from a table. Intermittently it is writing inconsistent data to files.

Comment: e.g. we have R1, R2, R3, R4 rows with C1, C2, C3 as column. Same C2 is repeating for R2 and R3 though the values should be different.

Comment: @Rahul Dey Can you add your configuration? .. seems very complex explained in few words